# Merge Sort Algorithm in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, mergesort

I've been trying to figure why my code is not working. I can't seem to figure it out. I've checked for code references out there but they all use "mergedArr.removeFirst()" which is computationally more expensive.

```
func mergeSort(arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    
    guard arr.count > 1 else {
        return arr
    }
    
    let middleIndex = arr.count / 2
    let leftArray = Array(arr[0..<middleIndex])
    let rightArray = Array(arr[middleIndex..<arr.count])
    
    
    return merge(left:mergeSort(arr: leftArray), right: mergeSort(arr: rightArray))
}

func merge(left: [Int], right: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    
    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = 0
    var mergedArr = [Int]()
    
    while leftIndex < left.count && rightIndex < right.count {
        if left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex] {
            mergedArr.append(left[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
        } else if left[leftIndex] > right[rightIndex]{
            mergedArr.append(right[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        } else {
            mergedArr.append(left[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
            mergedArr.append(right[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        }
    }
    
       return mergedArr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace internals of while- loop with simpler version

```
 while leftIndex < left.count && rightIndex < right.count {
    if left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex] {
        mergedArr.append(left[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
    } else {
        mergedArr.append(right[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
    }
 }
```

and you forgot about the rest of arrays:

```
 while leftIndex < left.count {
        mergedArr.append(left[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
 }
 while rightIndex < right.count {
        mergedArr.append(right[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
    }
```

Why? When you merge two arrays, tail of one array may be not treated yet. For example, you merge `[1 3 5] and [1 2]`. After copying to result `[1 1 2]` the second array is finished (`rightIndex` becomes equal to `right.count`) and main while-loop stops. But what about `[3,5]` piece?

Comment: Thank you @Mbo, can you please explain the second part of your code. The part about forgetting about the rest of the arrays.

Comment: Added to answer

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you forget to add to your ordered array the remaining data in left and right sub-array(s). The merge method should look like the below.

```
func merge<>(_ left: [Int], _ right: [Int]) -> [Int] {
  var leftIndex = 0
  var rightIndex = 0
  var orderedArray = [Int]()

  while leftIndex < left.count && rightIndex < right.count {
    let leftElement = left[leftIndex]
    let rightElement = right[rightIndex]

    if leftElement < rightElement {
      orderedArray.append(leftElement)
      leftIndex += 1
    } else if leftElement > rightElement {
      orderedArray.append(rightElement)
      rightIndex += 1
    } else {
      orderedArray.append(leftElement)
      orderedArray.append(rightElement)
      leftIndex += 1
      rightIndex += 1
    }
  }

  while leftIndex < left.count {
    orderedArray.append(left[leftIndex])
    leftIndex += 1
  }

  while rightIndex < right.count {
    orderedArray.append(right[rightIndex])
    rightIndex += 1
  }

  return orderedArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider if the data remains on the `left` or `right` only.

```
public func mergeSort<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> [T] {
    if array.count < 2 {
        return array
    }
    
    let mid = array.count / 2
    
    let left = [T](array[0..<mid])
    let right = [T](array[mid..<array.count])

    return merge(left, right)
}


private func merge<T: Comparable>(_ left: [T], _ right: [T]) -> [T] {
    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = 0
    var tempList = [T]()
    
    while leftIndex < left.count && rightIndex < right.count {
        if left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex] {
            tempList.append(left[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
            
        } else if left[leftIndex] > right[rightIndex] {
            tempList.append(right[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        }
        else {
            tempList.append(left[leftIndex])
            tempList.append(right[rightIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
            rightIndex += 1
        }
    }
    
    //Don't miss this part.
    while leftIndex < left.count {
        tempList.append(left[leftIndex])
        leftIndex += 1
    }
    
    while rightIndex < right.count {
        tempList.append(right[rightIndex])
        rightIndex += 1
    }

    return tempList
}
```